# What can cause SQL Server Full Text Indexing automatic change tracking to stop working?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

On a SQL Server 2008 server, we have a full text catalog in a database. The catalog is set to "track changes: automatic".

What can cause this to not work sporadically, so the index is not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188359.aspx

"SET CHANGE_TRACKING {MANUAL | AUTO | OFF} 
Specifies whether changes (updates, deletes, or inserts) made to table columns that are covered by the full-text index will be propagated by SQL Server to the full-text index. Data changes through WRITETEXT and UPDATETEXT are not reflected in the full-text index, and are not picked up with change tracking."